# What does the w flag mean when passed in via the ldflags option to the go command?

Tags: go

Context:

> go 1.2, ubuntu 12.10

Goal:

> Reduce size of compiled binaries

Currently in my build process, I run "go install" to generate the binary.
The I read from somewhere that if I pass in `-w` it will shrink the binary.
I tried it by passing it into the `-ldflags` option & my binary lost 1MB in size.

1. Is this `-w` flag documented anywhere? What does it actually do?
2. I then discovered the `strip -s <binary>` command and ran that on top of `-w` and got
   another weight loss of 750KB ! The resulting binary runs fine. Does stripping
   cause problems in any situations ?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You will get the smallest binaries if you compile with `-ldflags '-w -s'`.

The `-w` turns off DWARF debugging information: you will not be able to use `gdb` on the binary to look at specific functions or set breakpoints or get stack traces, because all the metadata `gdb` needs will not be included. You will also not be able to use other tools that depend on the information, like `pprof` profiling.

The `-s` turns off generation of the Go symbol table: you will not be able to use `go tool nm` to list the symbols in the binary. `strip -s` is like passing `-s` to `-ldflags` but it doesn't strip quite as much. `go tool nm` might still work after `strip -s`. I am not completely sure.

None of these — not `-ldflags -w`, not `-ldflags -s`, not `strip -s` — should affect the execution of the actual program. They only affect whether you can debug or analyze the program with other tools.

Comment: Note that if you're running prior to 1.2, stripping symbols may actually cause a program to misbehave. I don't remember exactly what change it was in 1.2 that fixed that, but certain operations (such as asking for the name of a function pointer using the runtime package) used to crash the program if symbols were stripped.

Answer (score 22):

You can get help from `go tool link`

```
$ go tool link
  ...
  -s    disable symbol table
  -w    disable DWARF generation
```

Answer (score 16):

The `go help build` says that

```
-ldflags 'flag list'
    arguments to pass on each 5l, 6l, or 8l linker invocation.
```

So, we can invoke `go tool 6l` to see all it's options. One of them is

```
-w  disable DWARF generation
```

By the way, `5l` stands for ARM (`$GOARCH = arm`), `6l` stands for x86-64 (`$GOARCH = amd64`), and `8l` is for x86 (`$GOARCH = 386`).

If you really want to view raw [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) info you should use `dwarfdump -a` on OS X and `objdump -wg` on Linux. Warning! Output will be long, very long.

Comment: What maps numbers to architectures? Why is `5l` ARM, `6l` x86-64, `8l` x86?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it *might* cause problems in programs compiled with Go 1.2's `gc` suite of tools—refer to [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/Xr2Zsa0YfKs/discussion).

The general idea is that while Go compiles down to machine code just like C, it's more higher-level than C.  For instance, it has built-in detailed `panic()` stack traces which depend on debug info.  The sizes of the `gc`-generated binaries could indeed have been smaller, and [it might be addresseed while cooking Go 1.3](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=6853), but really the size of a compiled program in most today's environments is not a big deal to be too concerned about.